# tomcat http server :: add # to requested URLs

Tags: angularjs, angular, tomcat, url, mapping

I am deploying a AngularJS web application on tomcat apache 7.0.76

I am deploying the app under the ROOT directory of the webapps

now whenever the URL is requested by the user i.e. www.mydomain.com , angular changes the directory to www.mydomain.com/#/ and any virtual sub-directory requested it will still be under the root (followed by the #). for an instance, if I clicked a link in the home page to enter faq page , it will take the user to something like www.mydomain.com/#/faq

now .. if user wants to access the faq page directly , he needs to enter the link as www.mydomain.com/#/faq and angular will know which template to load

so far no problem , now the issue when the user to access the page directly by entering www.mydomain.com/faq (without the #) , then the server returns that the page does not exist , because there is no physical page / directory called faq under the root

hence , what I am looking for , is there a possible way to check if the requested URL does not contain the # under the root to automatically add the # after the root. so if the user enters www.mydomain.com/faq it should re map it to www.mydomain.com/#/faq

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at this: [Tomcat Rewrite Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html)

Comment: thank you birwin - I am looking at the moment, will let you know shortly

Comment: eventually - I have to upgrade to tomcat 8 to enable the valve and make the rewrite conditions and rules and finally I was able to achieve it. Please post it an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tomcat Rewrite Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html) should allow you to redirect requests similar to apache mod_rewrite.